# How to change query string to json in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I just get started Wordpress and trying to change a query result to json in PHP and following is the query result.

```
user_id   meta_key      meta_value  
1        nickname       bko117
1        first_name     seokho
1        last_name      baek
1        genba          Company
1        Department     00
2        nickname       themedemos
2        first_name     
2        last_name 
3        nickname       john

.....
```

I want to change this data to json data

e.g :

```
"data":[
    {"nickname":"bko117", "first_name":"seokho","lastname":"baek","genba":"company","Department":"00" },
    {"nickname":"themedemos", "first_name":"","lastname":"","genba":"","Department":"" },
    {"nickname":"john", "first_name":"","lastname":"","genba":"","Department":"" },
    .......
   ]
```

When user_id changed, create new json array and put next on it.
This is what I want to make, and I've tried for more than 2 hours but still struggling with this matter.
Next code is what I've done so far.

```
<?php 
echo "1<br>";
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `user_id` , `meta_key` , `meta_value`
        FROM `wp_usermeta`
        WHERE `meta_key`
        IN (
        'nickname', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'Department', 'genba'
)
        ORDER BY `user_id` ASC
        LIMIT 0 , 999999");
echo "2<br>";
//print_r($results);
//print json_encode($results);
$dataArray = array();
echo "3<br>";
echo "4<br>";
foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row -> meta_key, ':';
    echo $row -> meta_value, '<br>';
}
print_r($data);
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your attention to this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below :

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach($results as $row){
    $dataArray[$row->user_id][$row->meta_key] = $row->meta_value;
}
print_r(json_encode($dataArray));
```

Comment: Thank you. now I got [{"nickname":"bko117"},{"first_name":"seokho"},{"last_name":"baek"},{"genba":"Company"},{"Department":"00"},{"nickname":"themedemos"}... This is better answer but I still want to get like this -> {"nickname":"bko117", "first_name":"seokho","lastname":"baek","genba":"company","Department":"00" }

Comment: Will you add `print_r($results);` output here?

Comment: Here is `print_r($results);` output. `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => nickname [meta_value] => bko117 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => first_name [meta_value] => seokho ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => last_name [meta_value] => baek ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => genba [meta_value] => Company ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 [meta_key] => Department [meta_value] => 00 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 2 [meta_key] => nickname [meta_value] => themedemos )`

Comment: Thanks a lot! finally it works. Now I got `{"1":{"nickname":"bko117","first_name":"seokho","last_name":"baek","genba":"Company","Department":"00"},"2":{"nickname":"themedemos","first_name":"","last_name":""},`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_encode` on the array with the desired structure, like so:

```
$dataArray = array();
foreach($results as $row){
$dataArray[$row->meta_key] = $row->meta_value;
}

print_r(json_encode($dataArray));
```

Comment: thank you for replying. I tried this code and it works somehow but I only get a last one. just {"nickname":"james","first_name":"\u672c\uff2a","last_name":"\u30e4\u30f3","genba":"Company","Department":"3"}, how could i get all data?